# Efficient way of calculating size of the objects in folder of a bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Somehow I want to get the total size of the folder for the user. Currently I am fetching all objects in memory and then looping all of them to add the size.

```
let promises = []

// the format of Key is "storage/{USER ID}/docs"
for (const Key of keys) { 
      promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        engineS3.getObject({
          Bucket: process.env.ENGINE_AWS_BUCKET,
          Key
        }, (e, data) => {
          resolve(data)
        })

      }))
    }

let docs = await Promise.all(promises)

let usedSpace = docs.reduce((x, y) => x + y.ContentLength, 0) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

For 2 3 documents (each of them ranges between 3mB to 10mB) it will work fine. But as number of users and documents grows, it might crash the server as of insufficient resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no simple way to achieve this but you can use AWS CLI command

**First Solution**

Run following command from your code. Use `child_process` or npm package like [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs). You also need to authenticate CLI in this case.

```
aws s3 ls s3://yourBucket/storage/{USER ID}/docs --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

This will return data like this:

```
2013-09-02 21:37:53   10 Bytes a.txt
2013-09-02 21:37:53  2.9 MiB foo.zip
2013-09-02 21:32:57   23 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/a
2013-09-02 21:32:58   41 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/b
2013-09-02 21:32:57  281 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/c
2013-09-02 21:32:57   73 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/d
2013-09-02 21:32:57  452 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/e
2013-09-02 21:32:57  896 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/bar
2013-09-02 21:32:57  189 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/foo
2013-09-02 21:32:57  398 Bytes z.txt

Total Objects: 10
Total Size: 2.9 MiB
```

And you can parse the total size from it.

**Second Solution**

Use Node AWS SDK's [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) method. Here catch is it only returns up to 1000 results in single call and provides marker for next page. You need to write logic for pagination.

Output will be:

```
{
    Contents: [
        {
            Key: "example1.jpg",
            // ... Other details
            Size: 11,
        },
        {
            Key: "example2.mp4",
            // ... Other details
            Size: 784335,
        },
    ],
    NextMarker: "eyJNYXJrZXIiOiBudWxsLCAiYm90b190cnVuY2F0ZV9hbW91bnQiOiAyfQ=="
}
```

You just need to add all the sizes.

**Third Solution**

If files are being uploaded from your platform then it's best to save content size somewhere in database and run query to get sizes.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i need the solution in nodejs. I am not using AWS CLI in the project

Comment: @tbhaxor Updated the answer. AWS CLI solution was also in node.js only as it's being invoked by node.js and installing it on your sever is single time process. I don't see any reason to downvote answer.